# Which Windows laptop is the best equivalent to a MacBook Pro for data science?

Tags: laptop, windows, performance, web-development, macbook

I am looking to buy Macbook Pro 13 inch with M2 chip, 8-core CPU, 10-core GPU, 8Gb unified memory, 512Gb SSD but I also wanted to consider other windows laptop since Mac is very expensive.
But I confused to choose best Windows laptop Equivalent to Macbook Pro 13 inch.
Mostly my work on Data Science and I also work on Mobile App development(Flutter & React native for Android).
I would appreciate any advice that would help to choose best one.

Comment: There are no similar options for that. M2 is ultra high performance (if ARM is what you are ok with) and nothing comes close to it that I know of. Also there is no Windows laptop with super high end CPU and GPU and basically no RAM AFAIK